# jQuery. Find all attribute values within/under elements `script or noscript or iframe` that have attribute keys as `src or href`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, cheerio

I want to be able to find all attribute values that have attributes keys as src or href under elements ('script', 'noscript', 'iframe').

Comment: Please show the HTML that you want to search, and can you clarify that you want values not the elements. Can you explain where the `src` or `href` is in `<noscript>`? How are you intending to store these values? In an array? Some exposition or code you've tried would be useful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("iframe[src], script[src]").each(function() {
console.log($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please see here : http://jsbin.com/kizix/1/edit

```
   $(function(){

    var elements = $("iframe[src], script[src], noscript[src]");
    $.each(elements, function(index,element){
      var src = $(element).attr('src');

      $('#sr').append(src + "<br/>");

    });

    });
```